# How can i retrieve the primary key from a Gridview row in aspx to use in a userControl.ascx?

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, visual-studio, gridview

I have a GridView with data bound fields from a mysql database. It contains two columns IdTask(primary key), 
TaskName and one button which opens a jQuery dialog.
I need to fill this dialog based on the on the ID of the task from the row i clicked the button. 
And i have a user control with another Gridview which contains said data that i need to display in the dialog.

This is what i have so far:

> The aspx Page:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".modalFiles").click(function () {
            var id = $(this).data("activitateId");
            console.log(id);
            $("#divModalFiles").dialog({
                dialogClass: "no-close",
                modal: true,
                title: "Files",
                width: 450,
                height: 440,
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                open: function (type, data) {
                    $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
                }

            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script> 
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="padding: 10px; width: 550px">
        <asp:GridView DataKeyNames="IdTask" ID="gvTask" runat="server"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="IdTask" HeaderText="ID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Task"  />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnFile" CssClass="btnFiles" runat="server" ImageUrl="img/files.png.png"/>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        <div id="divModalFiles" style="display:none">
                <ucFiles:Files runat="server"/>
            </div>
    </form>
    </body>
```

> The ascx userControl:

```
<div id="file">
          <asp:Literal ID="litMesaj" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Literal>
          <asp:FileUpload ID="fUpload" runat="server" />

          <br />
          <br />
          <asp:Label ID="lblDescFile" runat="server" Text="Description"></asp:Label>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescFile" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
          <br />
          <br />

          <asp:GridView ID="gvFiles" DataKeyNames="IdFiles" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No files uploaded">
              <Columns>
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="IdFiles" HeaderText="ID" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="IdTask" HeaderText="IdTask" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="File Name" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

                  <asp:TemplateField>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download File" OnClick="lnkDownload_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Url") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnDelFile" ImageUrl="~/delete.png.png" OnClientClick="return confirm('Sure?');" OnClick="btnDelFile_Click"/>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
              </Columns>              
          </asp:GridView>
      </div>
```

> The ascx.cs userControl

```
 // the function i call in page load to display the files
 private void loadFiles()
    {
        string sqlFiles = "select * from files where IdTask=" + ?? ;// here is where i need the help how can i retrieve the IdTask from the gridview on the aspx Page? 
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlFiles, conn);

    MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dtFiles = new DataTable();
    adp.Fill(dtFiles);
        gvFiles.DataSource = dtFiles;
        gvFiles.DataBind();
    }
```

Can you help me ? without that ID i can't use the download or the upload files functions either. It currently show only the form with the files upload and the upload button
If i didn't made myself clear(english is not my first language) with what i need please feel free to ask any questions and i will explain

Answer (score 0):

The first issue you have is that you need a postback in order to populate the popup.  That means a popup in an `<iframe>` that uses another, separate .aspx page that contains your user .ascx control. You pass `activitateId` via the URL.  NOTE: the `<iframe>` doesn't postback, but it *does* run the page lifecycle for the popup.aspx page without refreshing your main page.

```
<div id="divModalFiles" style="display:none">
    <iframe id="iframe_id" runat=server src="popup.aspx" ... />
</div>
```

Where `popup.aspx` contains:

```
<html>
<head> 
    whatever you need here
</head>
<body>  
  <ucFiles:Files runat="server"/>
</body>
</html>
```

In the JS/JQuery you modify the iframe src attribute before calling the popup:

```
function AlterIframeSrc( ID ) 
{
  $('#iframe_id').attr( 'src', 'popup.aspx?id=' + ID; );
}
```

---

### Option 2

Alternatively, depending on how much data the popup may contain, you could, create pre-loaded hidden div's within each row of the main gridview.
Drop your .ascx into the Main Gridview like any other server control and pass it the `activitateId` as a control parameter.

**HOWEVER** do this **ONLY** if for each `activitateId` you only get a small amount of data as this will impact performance.  **BUT** you no longer have to do a postback to get the data.

That's the trade off for the initial performance hit.
The advantage is that you can use simple javascript to wire up the popup.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnDelFile" ImageUrl="~/delete.png.png" OnClientClick="return confirm('Sure?');" OnClick="btnDelFile_Click"/>
     <div id="divModalFiles" style="display:none">
       <ucFiles:Files runat="server" IDTask='<%# Eval("activitateId") %>'/>
     </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The User Control attribute I added, `IDTask`, would be defined in your .ascx as a bindable public property.